# Count just columns consecutive in sheets

Tags: spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

I am trying to add or count only the values ​​that are consecutive between the columns, that is, I want to be able to identify by name when the condition that there is six times the number one is met, does anyone have any idea how to do it please? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of cells in a range that have a given value,
use the
[COUNTIF function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34).

In your case, the formula will be:

```
COUNTIF(K5:R5,1)
```